# Print bibliography: Empty bibliography

Tags: latex, bibliography, biblatex

It’s been days I’ve been looking for a valid solution, but it just never works.

The minimal reproducible example is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[authordate,autocite=inline,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{Test.bib}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}
\begin{document}

Test citing \citep{sanborn_learning_2014}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The Test.bib:

```
@article{sanborn_learning_2014,
    title = {Learning Democracy: Education and the Fall of Authoritarian Regimes},
    volume = {44},
    issn = {0007-1234, 1469-2112},
    url = {https://www.cambridge.org/core/product/identifier/S0007123413000082/type/journal_article},
    doi = {10.1017/S0007123413000082},
    shorttitle = {Learning Democracy},
    abstract = {Studies on what causes a state to democratize have focused on economic, social, and international factors. Many of them argue that higher levels of education should promote democracy. However, few articulate clearly how education affects democratization, and fewer still attempt to test the supposed link across time and space. This article fills that gap by considering how different levels of education influence democratization, and the conditions under which education is most likely to promote democracy. Analyses of eighty-five authoritarian spells from 1970 to 2008 find that higher levels of mass, primary, and tertiary education are robustly associated with democratization. Secondary analyses indicate that education is most effective in promoting democratization when both males and females are educated. An illustration from Tunisia follows.},
    pages = {773--797},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {British Journal of Political Science},
    shortjournal = {Brit. J. Polit. Sci.},
    author = {Sanborn, Howard and Thyne, Clayton L.},
    urldate = {2021-09-18},
    date = {2014-10},
    langid = {english},
```

The Test.blg:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14 (beta)
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'Test.blg'
[38] biber:322> INFO - === dim. sept. 19, 2021, 14:47:26
[48] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'Test.bcf'
[128] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 0 citekeys in bib section 0
[131] Utils.pm:293> WARN - The file 'Test.bcf' does not contain any citations!
[136] bbl.pm:652> INFO - Writing 'Test.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
[136] bbl.pm:755> INFO - Output to Test.bbl
[136] Biber.pm:128> INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```

The warning message when not citing in the text is `LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 16.`

The error and warning messages when citing in the text are:
On line 14:
`! Undefined control sequence.`
`! Missing $ inserted.`
`! Extra }, or forgotten $.`
On line 15:
`! Missing $ inserted.`
On line 16:
`LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 16.`

I’m running on Linux, Texlive2019 (apt installed that one, not a more recent one) and texmaker on Ubuntu 20.04.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: Your minimal working example is not complete. Do you actually `\cite` anything in your document? Do you run biber during the compilation?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes I do cite, but when I cite the following error appears: `! Undefined control sequence.`, `! Missing $ inserted.`, `! You can't use \spacefactor' in math mode.`, and `LaTeX Warning: Citation on page 1 undefined on input line 17.`. Nevertheless, I’d like all the entries in the .bib file even if they’re not cited in the text. And I do run biber during compilation.

Comment: This sounds like some bad code in your .bib file. Please make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: (to get all the entries in your .bib file shown in your bibliography, you can use `\nocite{*}`,  but as long as you still have to debug this error, focus on one entry first bofor adding them all)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I update the main question with the minimal reproducible example. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

- the `}` at the end of your bib entry was missing
- `\citep{}` is not provided by biblatex by default. You can use  `\parencite{}` instead or the `natbib=true` option of biblatex

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[authordate,autocite=inline,backend=biber,sorting=nyt,natbib=true]{biblatex-chicago}


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{sanborn_learning_2014,
    title = {Learning Democracy: Education and the Fall of Authoritarian Regimes},
    volume = {44},
    issn = {0007-1234, 1469-2112},
    url = {https://www.cambridge.org/core/product/identifier/S0007123413000082/type/journal_article},
    doi = {10.1017/S0007123413000082},
    shorttitle = {Learning Democracy},
    abstract = {Studies on what causes a state to democratize have focused on economic, social, and international factors. Many of them argue that higher levels of education should promote democracy. However, few articulate clearly how education affects democratization, and fewer still attempt to test the supposed link across time and space. This article fills that gap by considering how different levels of education influence democratization, and the conditions under which education is most likely to promote democracy. Analyses of eighty-five authoritarian spells from 1970 to 2008 find that higher levels of mass, primary, and tertiary education are robustly associated with democratization. Secondary analyses indicate that education is most effective in promoting democratization when both males and females are educated. An illustration from Tunisia follows.},
    pages = {773--797},
    number = {4},
    journaltitle = {British Journal of Political Science},
    shortjournal = {Brit. J. Polit. Sci.},
    author = {Sanborn, Howard and Thyne, Clayton L.},
    urldate = {2021-09-18},
    date = {2014-10},
    langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{202F}{\,}


\begin{document}

Test citing \citep{sanborn_learning_2014}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It’s working, thanks a lot! I don’t really get why it’s working now, because the `}` issue at the end of the .bib file was just due to a bad copy and paste on stack, and the `\parencite{}` should not be needed for the bibliography to print entirely anyways? So I’m not sure what was wrong... but thank you anyways

Comment: @Louis.vgn You're welcome!